# What's wrong with my SQL trigger

Tags: mysql

I need my SQL trigger to do the following:

When I insert row in the table user I want the two primary keys (ID, YEAR) to do the following: 1 - 2016   2 - 2016   3 - 2016   1 - 2017   2 - 2017

so basically I want the `autoincrement` to reset with a new year
the ID column is a INT(3) unsigned auto_increment field
the year column is a YEAR field type

The trigger I tried is

```
    CREATE TRIGGER reset BEFORE INSERT ON user FOR EACH ROW -- trigger creation
    BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(year) INTO @x FROM user; -- selecting max year from table to compare
    IF @x <> YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN -- if max from table differs from current
    ALTER TABLE user AUTO_INCREMENT=1; -- reset auto increment to 1  
    END IF;
    END;
```

but it keeps saying that there's an error in my SQL syntax

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two completely different products. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: I am not sure MySQL allows altering tables in triggers; even if it does, I know it does not allow modifying the contents of the table the trigger is for with UPDATEs and INSERTs, so I would not be surprised if at very least it did not permit ALTERs on the trigger's table either. Either way, that seems to be an abuse of auto_increment for a problem that could be more easily solved by just having the trigger calculate the id.

Comment: the question is about MySQL sorry :)

Comment: imo, No, you don't want the autoincrement to do anything other than autoincrement. i.e. **It should not be an autoincrement primary key** in this case. You look after it completely yourself. imo, Never fight the database engine over what you have told it to look after completely. It will end in tears (often at the first restore). Why? there are related tables that will get very confused. ;-/

Comment: If you ever have the need to reset the `auto_increment` field, just remember that you're doing something completely wrong. You don't have to know what immediately, but it's 100% undoubtedly wrong. `auto_increment` is not supposed to be used that way, you 100% don't have the need for it to behave like that. If you still want to do it - well, have fun and remember this post in a few months when something starts crashing without any visible reason.